# Create two arrays in descending order one even and second odd respectively

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

**Output should be like:**
Even Array in Descending Order:8
Even Array in Descending Order:6
Even Array in Descending Order:4
Even Array in Descending Order:2
Even Array in Descending Order:0
Odd Array in Descending Order:9
Odd Array in Descending Order:7
Odd Array in Descending Order:5
Odd Array in Descending Order:3
Odd Array in Descending Order:1

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,odd[5],even[5],temp;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
        if(i%2==0)
        {

                even[j]=i;
                j++;
        }
        else
        {

                odd[k]=i;
                k++;
        }
   }

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       for(j=1;j<6;j++)
       {
           if(even[i]<even[j])
           {
               temp=even[j];
               even[j]=even[i];
               even[i]=temp;
          }
       }
       printf("Even Array in Descending order: %d \n",even[i]);
   }

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       for(j=1;j<6;j++)
       {
           if(odd[i]<odd[j])
           {
               temp=odd[j];
               odd[j]=odd[i];
               odd[i]=temp;
           }
       }
       printf("Odd Array in Descending order: %d \n",odd[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual and specific question?

Comment: `for(j=1;j<6;j++)` That will cause an out of bounds access when `j` is `5` because the valid `even/odd` array indices are `0` to `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small error from your side, While sorting you are firstly exceeding the array bounds by running `for(j=1;j<6;j++)` and so what you need to do is make a couple of changes to your code.

First: For loop should run as

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {

    }
}
```

Second: Add a single `printf()` statement after the for loops since outer loop only runs 4 times.

Refer to this complete :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,odd[5],even[5],temp;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
        if(i%2==0)
        {

                even[j]=i;
                j++;
        }
        else
        {

                odd[k]=i;
                k++;
        }
   }

   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       for(j= i + 1;j<5;j++)
       {
           if(even[i]<even[j])
           {
               temp=even[j];
               even[j]=even[i];
               even[i]=temp;
          }
       }
       printf("Even Array in Descending order: %d \n",even[i]);
   }
    printf("Even Array in Descending order: %d \n",even[i]);
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       for(j= i + 1;j<5;j++)
       {
           if(odd[i]<odd[j])
           {
               temp=odd[j];
               odd[j]=odd[i];
               odd[i]=temp;
           }
       }
       printf("Odd Array in Descending order: %d \n",odd[i]);
   }
   printf("Odd Array in Descending order: %d \n",odd[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Visit this [link](http://ideone.com/W7BMxO) for demo

Happy to Help!